# Multiple conditions in jQuery filter method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
<div id="MetricsParentModelList">
   <ul>
      <li style=""><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
      <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Hello world 123</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add class "active" to that li whose display isn't none. I also have to compare the anchor tag text.

**My code is:**

```
$("#MetricsParentModelList li a").filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text().trim() === TextToCompare && $(this).parent().display != 'none')
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: why not just do it with the selector? `li:visible a`

Comment: What is problem? Your code work. http://jsfiddle.net/sfu9v6ob/ What

Comment: li:visible is not working . .@epascarello

Comment: no, its not workingfor me @Mohammad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the visible li's first using `:visible` selector, then you could filter the anchors with the `TextToCompare` and attach the class to them, like :

```js
var TextToCompare = 'Hello';

$("#MetricsParentModelList li:visible").filter(function() {
     return $('a', this).text().trim() === TextToCompare;
}).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MetricsParentModelList">
    <ul>
        <li style=""><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
        <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
        <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Hello world 123</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: purpose of each? i mean why should i use each instead of filter ?

Answer (score 0):

I can not find any reason to use `filter()` when the task is to add a class to some elements based on some condition. You can iterate over only visible `li` using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```js
$("#MetricsParentModelList li:visible").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() === 'Hello')
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MetricsParentModelList">
   <ul>
      <li style=""><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
      <li style="display:none"><a href="#">Hello world 123</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```